# basic PHP script outputs ";?> when executed

Tags: php, eclipse, tomcat7

I just started php. Wrote a simple file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>test

    <?php
    echo "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I would expect this to display:

> test Hello World!

But instead I get:

> test Hello World!"; ?>

This seems pretty basic, but I just don't get it.
I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.0.26.
When I run it with Eclipse I only get "*test*"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is PHP definitely handling the request? If not then the browser may just be making the best of what it has (i.e. strange tags).

Comment: Have you saved the file with a `.php` extension and not `.html` ?

Comment: try replacing double quotes with single quotes

Comment: Apache Tomcat is normally a server for Java. You have to explicitly set it up to work with PHP. Did you do that?

Comment: Do you have to be running Tomcat? Tomcats more for Java, if it's plain and simple PHP you're programming then just install Apache and PHP

Comment: What OS are you on? If it's windows I recommend this for easy install of apache php and mysql: http://wampserver.com/en , there are other out there too, this just happens to be the one I use.

Comment: I am getting the output as test Hello World as expected. Are you sure your apache is configured to handle php requests ? try writing '<?php phpInfo(); ?>` in a file and running that.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat doesn't parse PHP tags. You need a PHP server for this script to work. Id recommend running xampp (its portable, so no installation is needed) or wamp (on windows) or mamp on mac.

Any of these include all the required software for basic PHP/Apache/Mysql web development.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give xampp a try then.

Answer (score 0):

Basic troubleshooting tips:

1. Before you try out code, make sure PHP is installed and working.
2. Use your browser's "View source" feature to inspect the actual output of your PHP script.
3. Make sure you enable full error reporting in your development box. Find your `php.ini` file and set:

   - `display_errors = On`
   - `error_reporting = E_ALL`
4. Learn to use [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) and [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump).